# How to cast to the right ancestor class so a template-specialization is defined

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

I get a compiler error

```
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../main.cpp:38:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘do_stuff(x&)’
../main.cpp:38:16: note: candidate is:
../main.cpp:30:6: note: template<class M> void do_stuff(M, typename a<M>::is_valid_type)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

for the following code:

```
template<typename S>
class a
{
};

template<typename T>
class b
{
};

class x: public b<int>
{
};

template<typename T>
class a<b<T> >
{
public:
  typedef void* is_valid_type;
};

template<typename M>
void do_stuff(M thing, typename a<M>::is_valid_type t = 0)
{
  a<M> whatevs;
}

int main()
{
  x my_x;
  do_stuff(my_x);
}
```

Here I want to implicitly cast an object of type x to some superclass M for which a<M>::is_valid_type is defined (in this case b<int>).  But this doesn't seem to work.  How can I do this?

(without using any c++-11 constructs)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the compiler will not match a template specialization for `b<int>` with a template argument of `x`, even though `x` inherits from `b<int>`, because for a template specialization to be chosen by the compiler, the types must match exactly.

Instead, if you want to ensure that a template parameter is an instance of a class that is derived from some base class, you might consider something like:

```
template<typename TDerived, typename TBase>
struct AssertInheritedType
{
    inline AssertInheritedType(void)
    {
        if (false)
        {
            TBase * p1 = static_cast<TDerived *>(0);    // If compiler error here, TDerived* cannot be implicitly cast into TBase*
            p1 = p1;
        }
    } // AssertInheritedType()
}; // struct AssertInheritedType
```

To use this, you would do:

```
template<typename M>
void do_stuff(M thing)
{
    AssertInheritedType<M, b<int> >();
    a<M> whatevs;
}
```

This would cause the compilation of an instance of `do_stuff()` to fail if the parameter has not been derived from `b<int>`.  However, passing an `x` to `do_stuff()` should work if `x` has been derived from `b<int>`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know TBase, so it's not good enough to make an assertion.  There are multiple potential bases and I want things to behave differently depending on which one is actually an ancestor class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. Two different instances of a template don't have anything in common, it doesn't work like inheritance.

```
class x : public b<int>
{
};
class y : public b<float>
{
};
```

Here classes x and y don't have a common ancestor, because b and b are quite different classes.

EDIT:
You can provide an ancestor for b class, which is not a template. I don't know other ways to specialize this template, in C++11 it will look like:

```
#include <type_traits>

class b_base
{
};
template<typename S,typename U = void>
class a;

template<typename T>
class b: public b_base
{
};

class x : public b<int>
{
};
class z
{
};

template<typename T>
class a<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<b_base, T>::value>::type>
{
};

int main()
{
  //this works
  a<x> c1;
  //this doesn't
  a<z> c1;
}
```

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I realized what I really want to ask.  Could you take another look?  Thank you